# Recommended cache control method?

Tags: javascript, css, dependencies

I'm looking to force refreshes of JS/CSS dependencies.

Will `<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">` work for that, or will that only force a refresh of the content within the page itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it controls only current document. If you dont want ugly URIs with random query-strings, its the time to configure your server. Assuming Apache:

```
# mod_expires directives: 
# enable expires/max-age headers and set default to 0 seconds from last access time
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A0
# configure ExpiresByType on your specific types, eg ExpiresByType text/css A0



# mod_headers directives:
# send variety of no-cache directives, should cover any quirky clients and gateways
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, no-transform"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
# enclose this in <Files> directive for specific file eg <Files *.js>
```

---

These directive groups will work in per-directory configs (`.htaccess` files) too (in case of shared environment hosting), given following requirements met:

1. `AllowOverride FileInfo` is in effect
2. Either `mod_expires` or `mod_headers` is enabled

If both are enabled - note that groups are overlapping on `max-age`, you will want to remove it from `Header` and use finer control via `ExpiresXXXX`. 
Described setup is rather common for the shared hosting environment, so ask server admin or just try yourself (will return `500 Internal Server Error` if corresponding module is not enabled or have no effect if `.htaccess` processing is not enabled)

Comment: Not my server... doh. :)  I like this method the best, even though I am unable to use it.

Comment: @Michael, sorry, i didn't mention .htaccess for shared hostings, updated on that.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a server-side language to append a timestamp to each file being pulled in:

```
<?php $timestamp = time(); ?>
<link href="shell.css?timestamp=<?=$timestamp?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I've found that meta cache tags don't work consistently cross-browser, so this is my go-to if I need to force-reload something on page refresh.

Comment: Right. It also might make more sense to use the file's modification date, rather than the current time, so that the file is reloaded only when it needs to be instead of on every page load.

Answer (score 3):

The above answer works, though I'd probably rather use a `?version=1`at the end, so that it will cache when there are no changes. Also setting the webservers cache-policies is effective.

This is a good article on explaining caching for webpages: http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/